# How to compile to a different location

Tags: compilation, d, flags

I am very new to using the a command line to compile code so I was wondering how to make the D compiler compile all its code to a certain location instead of where the source is. As in I want the final .exe and the obj code all in a particular directory. I know you can use the -of command but I currently don't know the format for using it. 
Currently I have:

```
C:\D\dmd2\windows\bin\dmd.exe -w C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\D\Test.d C:\Users\Kyle\Desktop\D\src\MyMod.d
```

What do I need to add?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `-offilename` switch. Example:

```
dmd factorial.d -offilename "d:\test_name.exe"
```

or short version:

```
dmd factorial.d "-ofd:\test_name.exe"
```

*Note: The double quotes are necessary if your path contains spaces.*

*Note2: In short version you can skip `.exe`, but don't do it in full version, because compiler would search for source file with that name.*

Comment: I thought it was `dmd factorial.d "-ofd:\test_name.exe"`

Comment: I bet it is so because it is not clear what is the switch, from the DMD help, so they let both -of and -offilename :)

Comment: And those who do not like switches to be joined with arguments will hate DMD, because they can't do `-of c:/path/to/file.exe` ...

Comment: @DejanLekic `-offilename c:/path/to/file.exe`?

Comment: @sigod I did not try that... Too long... :)

Answer (score 1):

I know people do not like RTFM answers, but the following is kind of RTFM answer that answers your question:

Execute `dmd --help` and you will get the following:

```
DMD32 D Compiler v2.061
Copyright (c) 1999-2012 by Digital Mars written by Walter Bright
Documentation: http://www.dlang.org/index.html
Usage:
  dmd files.d ... { -switch }

  files.d        D source files
  @cmdfile       read arguments from cmdfile
  -c             do not link
  -cov           do code coverage analysis
  -D             generate documentation
  -Dddocdir      write documentation file to docdir directory
  -Dffilename    write documentation file to filename
  -d             silently allow deprecated features
  -dw            show use of deprecated features as warnings (default)
  -de            show use of deprecated features as errors (halt compilation)
  -debug         compile in debug code
  -debug=level   compile in debug code <= level
  -debug=ident   compile in debug code identified by ident
  -debuglib=name    set symbolic debug library to name
  -defaultlib=name  set default library to name
  -deps=filename write module dependencies to filename
  -g             add symbolic debug info
  -gc            add symbolic debug info, pretend to be C
  -gs            always emit stack frame
  -H             generate 'header' file
  -Hddirectory   write 'header' file to directory
  -Hffilename    write 'header' file to filename
  --help         print help
  -Ipath         where to look for imports
  -ignore        ignore unsupported pragmas
  -inline        do function inlining
  -Jpath         where to look for string imports
  -Llinkerflag   pass linkerflag to link
  -lib           generate library rather than object files
  -man           open web browser on manual page
  -map           generate linker .map file
  -noboundscheck turns off array bounds checking for all functions
  -O             optimize
  -o-            do not write object file
  -odobjdir      write object & library files to directory objdir
  -offilename    name output file to filename      <---- [1]
  -op            do not strip paths from source file
  -profile       profile runtime performance of generated code
  -property      enforce property syntax
  -quiet         suppress unnecessary messages
  -release       compile release version
  -run srcfile args...   run resulting program, passing args
  -unittest      compile in unit tests
  -v             verbose
  -version=level compile in version code >= level
  -version=ident compile in version code identified by ident
  -vtls          list all variables going into thread local storage
  -w             warnings as errors (compilation will halt)
  -wi            warnings as messages (compilation will continue)
  -X             generate JSON file
  -Xffilename    write JSON file to filename
```

I marked the line that answers your question with **[1]** and an arrow.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at the `-of`, `-od` and `-op` switches. It's hard to be more specific without knowing what exactly you mean by "compile all its code to a certain location".